# How do I validate a username using php?

Tags: php, regex, validation

How do I validate a username using PHP?

On my registration page I need to validate the usernames.

**Acceptable (for example) Only letters, numbers and _ :**

- anas fares
- anasfares
- AnAsFaReS
- anas45 fares
- 35fares arty
- anas_fares

**Unacceptable (for example) :**

- anas.fares
- anas #fares
- 57fares
- @^*12sf
- anas-fares

Comment: Why are your usernames so restrictive in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regular expression to restrict the characters which a string may contain. In PHP, [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will return 0 if the pattern isn't matched, non-zero otherwise:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[ \w]+$/', $username)) {
  $error = "Invalid username";
}
```

You should also enforce a minimum/maximum length with either `strlen` or a modified regular expression. This one only matches strings from two to ten characters in length:

```
/^[ \w]{2,10}$/
```

Comment: You'd need to add `a-zA-Z` to that regex, otherwise you're just matching numeric digits, spaces and `-`...

Comment: and these darn blind upvotes again. these lemmings tend to upvote blindly!

Comment: @Col @ircmaxell Thanks, my mistake. I meant to use `\w`, and mistakenly thought that hyphens were allowed in the name. Fixed.

Comment: How can i use [ء-ي ]+ with ^[ \w]+$ to accept eng and arabic letters ?

Comment: @faressoft "A special option is the /u which turns on the Unicode matching mode, instead of the default 8-bit matching mode. You should specify /u for regular expressions that use \x{FFFF}, \X or \p{L} to match Unicode characters, graphemes, properties or scripts. PHP will interpret '/regex/u' as a UTF-8 string rather than as an ASCII string." [regex.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)